# JsonCpp - Zero after decimal point is truncated

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I recently upgraded to JsonCpp version 1.6.5.

I have noticed that floating point numbers where the digit after the decimal point is zero are truncated when printed. For example `2.0` is printed as `2`

The previous version I was using (v0.6.0) did not do this.

Is this behaviour expected?

**UPDATE**

The following code demonstrates the issue described:

```
Json::Value object;
object["float1"] = 2.0f;
object["float2"] = 2.1f;

Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;
std::cout << styledWriter.write(object);
```

The output when run on OS X using Xcode 6.3.2 is:

```
{
   "float1" : 2,
   "float2" : 2.0999999046325684
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of code that exhibits the issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's not surprising.  The JSON format only has a NUMBER datatype.  It doesn't distinguish between Integer and Floating Point.  (Of course receiving code may only be prepared to accept integer values in certain fields, but that's a different question.  Almost all clients can accept a number without a decimal point when they are expecting a floating point value).

Comment: But why the difference in output between the versions?

Comment: You would have to look at the diffs to answer that.

Comment: Couldn't find anything to explain it. Hence the question.